# How to figure out what slowly eats my Macbook Pro's disk space until I reboot?

Tags: macos, disk-space

When I boot up my computer (OS X El Capitan), I have about 5GB spare disk space. Then, over the course of several hours, it gradually approaches zero. (If I let it reach zero, I get a warning message and my system grinds to a halt.)

When I restart the computer, I have 5GB free again. This has been going on for months.

I'm guessing some app is running rampant with creating temp files (or maybe just one big temp file somewhere). But I don't know how to work out which app it is. If I look in "All my files" in Finder, and sort by most recently added, there is nothing new there. So it must be happening in some system temp directory outside my account. Is there a command I can use to list the most recently modified files *anywhere* on my computer?

Answer (score 2):

Beside what is written in your own cache files; `/private/tmp`, `/private/var/tmp`, `/private/var/folders` hold temporary files. Virtual memory is also a factor- `/private/var/vm`.

Your disk does not have enough free disk space to operate properly.

Comment: How much free disk space is needed to operate properly, and why?

Comment: @callum - the amount of free disk space needed depends upon your hardware configuration and the applications that you use. Ten percent free disk space as a starting point. This would perhaps give virtual memory enough space to grow and room for temporary files.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely temporary files or caches are causing this. You can use a free disk space app to narrow it down or run the following terminal command to get a summary. Obviously you'll have to run it every so often to get an idea of what's going on.

```
sudo du -chd 1 /
```